# Mean of polygons area within another polygon layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, intersection, area

I have the following layers :

- Sectors (polygons limited by the black lines)
- Houses (polygons in light blue)

I have created the area attribute in the Houses table. I have also created an attribute that represents the centroid of the geometry.

**I would like to calculate the mean area of Houses located in each sector and add it as an attribute of the Sectors table.**
A house is considered "in the sector" if its centroid is in the sector (to avoid problems with houses over 2 different sectors).

I don't know how to do this "group by" operation and haven't found answers searching this stack.

[image: ScreenShoot in QGIS, two layers]

Comment: Start with Intersect then try for example Group Stats etc.

Comment: In DB manager you can use SQL on virtual layers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this expression on your `Sectors` layer's attribute table:

```
aggregate(layer := 'Houses', 
          aggregate:= 'mean', 
          expression:= "area", 
          filter:= within(centroid($geometry), geometry(@parent)))
```

A quick test output ("ave" field) below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the mean area of houses using the Field Calculator to create a new field in the *Sectors* layer.

Use this expression

```
(to_string(array_sum(aggregate(
 layer:= 'Houses',
 aggregate:='array_agg',
 expression:=$area,
 filter:=contains(geometry(@parent), $geometry)))))
  /
(aggregate(
layer:='Houses', 
aggregate:='count', 
expression:=$id, 
filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), ($geometry))))
```

The first part of the expression calculates the sum of all the *Houses* areas inside each sector. The second part calculates the number of *Houses* inside the sector. 
A simple division of the first number by the second will give you the request information